# Reporting Services hiding duplicates by using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005

I want to create a report based on 3 tables called `Physician`, `Credentials` and `Insurance`. All these tables are related to `Physician` and linked by `physician Id`.

I want to display rows based on `physician id` but suppress the duplicate values. How to display the physician, credentials and insurance details in one report based on physician id?

Here the problem is one physician contains more than one credential and insurance details. Suppose for `physician id=1` he contains credentials like A,B and and insurance like C,D my report is coming like this

```
physician id  credentials insurance

     1         A          C
     1         A          D
     1         B          C    
     1         B          D
```

BUT I want my report like

```
physician id  credentials insurance

     1         A          C
               B          D
```

SO I want to display the details once and want to hide the duplicate values

Is there any possibility by using sub reports please mind I am using SQL Server 2005 and ssrs 2005.

Sorry for my bad language plz help for this thanks  @anil@

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a 3 column table to your report
2. Create a group on PhysicianID
3. Make PhysicianID the value in the first column on the group header row
4. On the 2nd column, add a List.
5. Right click the List and click properties --> Edit details group...
6. Select =Fields!Credentials.Value in the group on expression dropdown
7. Add a textbox to the list and set value to =Fields!Credentials.Value
8. Follow steps 4-7 for the 3rd column

Summary:
Add a List to a group header and group the list by the value you want to get the "distinct" value, the put that value in a textbox, which will then repeat for that group.

[image: groupingExample]